# Avoiding duplicate code in C++ template implementation

Tags: c++, generics, typename

I split a generic class into a header and implementation file as follows.

Test.h:

```cpp
#ifndef MY_DESCRIPTIVE_GUARD_NAME
#define MY_DESCRIPTIVE_GUARD_NAME

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
    T myObj;

public:
    MyClass(T& obj);
    void set(T& obj);
    T get();  
}

#include "Test.tpp"
#endif
```

Test.tpp:

```cpp
template<typename T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass(T& obj) {
    // implementation
}
// etc.
```

But as I add more methods to `MyClass`, I keep having to write the same boilerplate:

```cpp
template<typename T> return-type MyClass<T>::method_name
```

With dozens of methods (not to mention if I include more template parameters), I'm writing *a lot* of repeated code. Should I use a macro? Suck it up? Or is there a feature in the language that allows me to package multiple method implementations in one unit, almost as if they were defined in the header file?

Comment: What you could do is to move implementations into a class declaration.

Comment: Doesn’t that negate all the benefits of having an implementation file separate from the header?

Comment: I don't see any real benefits in doing so. This makes some files (`.tpp`) not self-contained and not compilable.